# Provided og:image URL, image.png was not valid because it did not meet the minimum size constraint of 200px by 200px

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, share-button

facebook debugger gives me Provided og:image URL, https://covid2019.cf/images/searchwilaya.png was not valid because it did not meet the minimum size constraint of 200px by 200px.

even tho my picture is 615w 330h.

any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: When do you get that error?

Comment: Did you recently change what image that URL returns? I put it into the debug tool directly, and it showed old cached data from 9 hours ago first, and said the image was 400something x 145 pixels. After a re-scrape, it now shows 615 x 330, so the problem appears to be fixed by now?